Is there any need to perform preprocessing while using LlamaParser & MarkdownElementNodeParser? how can I add additional steps for Preprocessing?
Improved response:
I am developing a Retrieval Augmented Generation (RAG) based application that involves extracting data from a large PDF file containing over 200 pages. To accomplish this, I am using LlamaParser to extract data from the PDF and convert it to Markdown format, followed by using MarkdownElementNodeParser to parse the Markdown data.
My question is related to preprocessing - do LlamaParser and MarkdownElementNodeParser perform any preprocessing by default, such as lowercasing, stopword removal, or punctuation removal? If not, is it necessary to perform preprocessing in a RAG based application? I have not tried any preprocessing steps yet as I am unsure if it is necessary or if it is already being done by the parsers I am using. I expected that LlamaParser and MarkdownElementNodeParser might perform some basic preprocessing, but I have not been able to find any information regarding this.
If preprocessing is necessary, I would like to know how to add custom preprocessing steps to my current pipeline. Below is the code I am currently using:
parser = LlamaParse(api_key= API_Key, result_type="markdown", verbose=True)
doc = parser.load_data(file_path=file_path)

node_parser = MarkdownElementNodeParser(llm=None, num_workers=4)

nodes = node_parser.get_nodes_from_documents(doc)

base_nodes, objects = node_parser.get_nodes_and_objects(nodes)

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

By default LlamaParser and MarkdownElementNodeParser do not perform any preprocessing that alters the actual text like lowercasing, or stopword removal.
These have different jobs:
parser = LlamaParse(api_key= API_Key, result_type="markdown", verbose=True)
doc = parser.load_data(file_path=file_path)

These lines of code read and parse the document as a whole and put it as a list of document objects in the doc variable.
Next,
nodes = node_parser.get_nodes_from_documents(doc)

The MarkdownElementNodeParser takes the parsed document and converts it into interconnected nodes/chunks of smaller data, There are two types of nodes, TextNode, which contains text and IndexNode, which contains majorly tables and other objects.
base_nodes, objects = node_parser.get_nodes_and_objects(nodes)

These nodes are then logically separated in base_nodes and objects, although base_nodes may also contain IndexNode after this process.
